# Installed update for Windows 10- now unable to access network drives...?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ssh, windows-update

Yesterday, at the end of the day, I was part way through implementing some changes to some software that I was working on using a virtual machine (CentOS 5- which is where I do all of the development work prior to pushing the updates to the live version of the software).

After implementing the changes, I ran my local version of the software again using the commands `python2.6 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` & `python2.6 manage.py runsoftware`, which are the commands I always use to get my development version up and running, so that I could see the effect that the changes I had made would have.

As I hadn't finished working on that particular feature yesterday, I left my computer running overnight, with the server and the software still running on the VM. When I got in this morning, I finished off the task I had been working on, and then tried to restart the server & the local software in order to see the changes I had made, but the terminal I had been using to do this in the VM didn't seem to be responding.

So, I closed the terminals on the VM, shut the VM down & restarted my computer. While my computer was restarting, it also installed some Windows updates.

However, now that my computer has restarted, I have found that I am no longer able to access a couple of network drives that I had previously been able to access (never had any issues accessing these in the past, whether after Windows updates/ restarts, or at any other time).

I can still see the drives in the File Explorer window, but when I first clicked on them, another window (which looked like a Windows 10 'security' type one) opened up asking me for some login credentials- which I have not had to provide since mapping these drives to my computer. I tried my Windows login credentials, and some other ones used by the company for things that certain employees have access to, but none of these worked.

[image]

After the failed login attempt, another dialog (which looks like a normal 'window') opened up titled 'Restoring Network Connections', which says:

> An error occurred while reconnecting K: to \server\shared
>
> Microsoft Windows Network: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
>
> This connection has not been restored.

[image: Error connecting to drive]

I know that there is no problem at all with the network drive I am trying to access, because my colleagues still have access to it.

I have tried accessing the network both through an Ethernet connection, and over WiFi, but am unable to connect to the drive.

The Update History on my computer says that the last update installed was:

> 2018-05 Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64-based System (KB4134661)
>
> Successfully installed on 16/05/2018

Is it possible that the Windows update that was just installed has somehow removed/ blocked my access to the network drive? How can I restore access to the network drives?

**Edit**

So I have managed to get access to the previously mapped network drives by re-mapping them- although I still have to enter a user name and password every day in order to access them, where I didn't have to previously, but I'm still having another problem that appears to be network related, which has only started happening since this Windows update was installed.

I regularly use [PuTTy](https://www.putty.org/) to SSH into our server in order to perform maintenance tasks, etc. However, since this update was installed, I am no longer able to SSH into the server... When I open PuTTy, & select the server from the list of saved sessions, the login screen is displayed:

[image: server login]

I have the private key saved on my computer, so enter the user I want to log in as, and press enter.

Usually, the private key would be loaded, and I would be logged in automatically- and see that the command prompt is at the root directory of the server.

However, since this Windows update has been installed, I now can't seem to connect to the server- when I select the server from the list of saved sessions, and am prompted to enter a username, I enter the same one as I had previously, and press Enter, but am presented with a dialog stating that there has been a fatal error:

[image: server login error]

I also get the same login error when trying to SSH into another address in my saved sessions:

[image: BM login error]

Anyone have any ideas why this is? It seems that the Windows update has changed some network setting or something, that is now preventing me accessing anything outside my local network, and also restricting access to things on my local network... How can I identify what it is I need to change to restore this to how it was working prior to the Windows update?

Comment: KB4134661 is related to privacy concerns, so doesn't seem problematic. Try these [network troubleshooting measures](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10741/windows-fix-network-connection-issues) and then try to delete and recreate the shares.

Comment: Ask your Administrator to remove the update to confirm if the update is the cause for this behavior

Comment: The update was the last thing that happened before I started having this problem, so I think it must be the cause of it... As I mentioned in my edit, I managed to get the drives up again by re-mapping them, but I'm still having the problems trying to SSH into the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the problem here was that for some reason (presumably during the Windows update), the SSH private keys had been removed from Pageant (the SSH authentication agent I am using). Once I had added these again, I was able to log in successfully.